# My custom VSCode extsion works fine debugging but not when installed

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am working on a custom language extension for VSCode and everything is working perfectly fine while I am debugging. However, the installed VSIX doesn't seem to have any of the TypesSript driven features. Opening up the correct file extension type will highlight everything, show the scripting language in the corner of VSCode and doesn't throw visible errors, but that is about all I get from it.

Which is weird because I opened the **installed** folder, ran npm install, added a .vscode folder, a launch.json file, actually executed the compiled JavaScript in debug mode and again it all works just fine!

I am really confused, does anyone have some ideas of what could cause this? My project code can be found here:
https://github.com/AgileBIM/FabCOD

Answer (score 1):

I'll understand if this gets entirely deleted, but I think this could save somebody some time.

Admittedly a very dumb solution:

make sure the "node_modules" folder isn't in the .vscodeignore file.